# display:none to display:block - How do I get the page to scroll down?

Tags: javascript, css

I am using javascript to change the display of a div tag with an onclick event. The div is at the bottom of the page, when and/or if needed the user can open the div. How can I get the page to scroll down when this div is changed to display:block?

FYI: I have tried

```
var objDiv = document.getElementById("the_div_id");
objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
```

The page just won't scroll down. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var objDiv = document.getElementById("the_div_id");
objDiv.scrollIntoView();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work

Add an anchor by the div

```
<a href="#div" id="showDivTrigger">
<a name="div"></a>
<div style="display:none;">
contents
</div>
<script>
var element = document.getElementById('#div');
element.style.display = '';
</script>
```

Comment: This did work for the first instance. After the first call to the div, it didn't work again. I used:

Comment: location.href=location.href + '#tt' then at the bottom of the page <a name="tt"></a>

Answer (score 0):

[scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollTop) only makes sense on elements which themselves have a scrollbar (or do not, but can be scrolled). From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534618(VS.85).aspx): *This property is always 0 for objects that do not have scroll bars. For these objects, setting the property has no effect.*

You chould set `body.scrollTop` instead (or use [window.scrollTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.scrollTo) which has the same effect), for which you need the absolute position of the element in the page, which you can get by walking up the element's [offsetParent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetParent) chain and summing up [offsetTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetTop) distances. You are probably better off using a framework, e.g. jQuery's [offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) method, than doing this manually. (Of course, if you only need to jump to the element and not visually scroll, then [mplungjan's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693944/displaynone-to-displayblock-how-do-i-get-the-page-to-scroll-down/3693980#3693980) is the simplest.)